# Get "No module named 'pandas.tslib'" error while importing xarray

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-xarray

While importing xarray following error was observed. Earlier it was running fine. Does anyone have any suggestions for why?

```
import xarray as xr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jives/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .core.dataset import Dataset
  File "/home/jives/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .. import conventions
  File "/home/jives/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.tslib import OutOfBoundsDatetime
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tslib'
```

Comment: what versions of pandas and xarray. Perhaps you updated one of the 2 without also updating the other, resulting in incompatibilities

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. your suggestion helped me correct the problem.